# Is there a way to "shrink" the desktop to match screen real estate?

Tags: windows-7, display

I have a damaged monitor where a large chunk is blurry. It becomes annoying to have to resize my windows when having them fit in the bottom portion of the screen. For example, I might accidentally snap a window to the bottom of the screen, causing it to maximize, which is not my intent. Is there a way to have to maximize up to the part where the screen is unusable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most promising way to do that is by tweaking your graphics driver settings, so that the the newly defined desktop size and position is transparently handed to your OS.

I just checked on my computer with an Nvidia GPU and a 1900x1200 monitor: you can set the resolution to 1280x1024 and specify that no scaling should take place. Now I have a "complete" 1280x1024 desktop in the middle off my monitor, with a black offset of some centimeters to the physical frame. I think this is probably what you want. Maybe you can even specify *where* to display the unscaled view area on the physical screen, but this completely depends on your driver.

Comment: Turning off no scaling, but it doesn't seem to have an effect.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? You should turn ON "no scaling", so to say.

Comment: That's what I meant, sorry. When I adjust the position, it moves the entire screen.

Comment: Ah, I see, it had to be done on the GPU.